# creating a gradient as background color from image colors in css

Tags: html, web, gradient, background-color, mix-blend-mode

hi so I'm trying to change the background color of a div when I hover over it, in this div I have an image and some text. how can I change the background color into a gradient based on the image in the div?
I tried using blend mode for background but I'm not really sure I'm using it correctly, also the result is not really a gradient I would need to blur it.

```css
.grid1:hover {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
      
img {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
 <div style="
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:  250px 250px 250px 250px 250px;
    column-gap: 20px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px">
      <div style="border-radius: 20px" class="grid1">
        <div>
          <img class="pictures" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510__340.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="title" >
            WNEO 88.3 PM 30 Max PL-XVII/Lluv Quest; 
          </p>
          <p class="info">
            <i>- Non lo so, - rispose Tsukuru. - Lui e io viviamo in mondi lontani anni luce. Non è facile capire per me se fa bene o male.</i>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You want to add gradient overlay to image or div(background) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gradient to set gradient background image. There are three types of gradients Linear, Radial, Conical. It is better if you use designing tools like figma to choose background color and then take the CSS code.

```css
img
{
width:100%;
}

.grid1:hover{
background-image:linear-gradient(red,yellow);
}
```

```html
<div style="
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:  250px 250px 250px 250px 250px;
    column-gap: 20px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px">
      <div style="border-radius: 20px" class="grid1">
        <div>
          <img class="pictures" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510__340.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="title" >
            WNEO 88.3 PM 30 Max PL-XVII/Lluv Quest; 
          </p>
          <p class="info">
            <i>- Non lo so, - rispose Tsukuru. - Lui e io viviamo in mondi lontani anni luce. Non è facile capire per me se fa bene o male.</i>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```